# graphql-scalars: BigInt doublequoted as string

Tags: graphql

I'm using graphql-scalars in order to have BigInt type in my graphql schema. It runs but that BigInts have this format:
{

"data": {

"createStage": "41"

}

}
It is doublequoted so it is not an numeric type but an string. Am I doing something in bad way?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is intended behavior. The BigInt scalar can represent integers that are larger than [what JavaScript supports](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER) (9007199254740991), so the value is always serialized as a string in the response.